# not able to add list item between a list using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, append, nested-lists

I m having a ordered list having the structure

```
<ol>
      <li>
      </li>
      <li>
      </li>
      <li>
         <ol>
              <li>
                 Test
              </li>
              <li>
                 another test
              </li>
              <li>
                   <a href='#'>Add </a>
              </li>
         </ol>
      </li>

</ol>
```

I want to add a list item between sublist 2 and 3 using jquery

I used the code: -

```
$("ol#update li ol li:eq(1)").append("<li> test </li>");
```

But this appends inside the li "another test" and not after the 2 li

Here is the [example page](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/divcomment.jsp)

On-click "sub-comment" adds a li inside li 2 
Clicking on "comment" shows the structure of the sub lis

Please help

Thanks

Pradyut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of `append`

Comment: thanks for the lightening fast answer...:-)
btw where do i find a list of jquery functions....thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not big into jquery... but using normal javascript functions (as well) you can do:

```
var item = $("ol#update li ol li:eq(1)");
var thingToAppend = document.createElement('li');
thingToAppend.innerHTML = ' test ';
item.parentNode.insertBefore(item, thingToAppend);
// or
item.parentNode.appendChild(thingToAppend);
// or apparently.... with jQuery something like:
item.after(thingToAppend);
```